# Скрипт работает один раз из 10

Tags: javascript, css

Здравствуйте! Для выравнивания по высоте в блоке, тянущемся по высоте, я использую скрипт. Во всех браузерах, кроме ie, он отлично работает. А в ie работает примерно 1 раз из 10, в основном не срабатывает, т.е. выравнивания по вертикали не происходит. Не 
    подскажете, почему такое может быть?

```
$(function () { 
    setAlign();

    $(window).resize(function () {
        setAlign();
    });
});

function setAlign() {
    $('div.window').each(function () {
        var outerHeight = parseInt($(this).height());
        var innerHeight = parseInt($(this).find('div.car-text').first().height());
        var margin = (outerHeight - innerHeight) / 2 - 5;
        $(this).find('div.car-text').first().css('margin-top', margin);
    });

    var tds = $('div.top-dialog-small').height();
    var ni = 0;
    $('div.header-left div.news div.news-item').each(function () {
        var niHeight = $(this).height();
        if (niHeight > ni) {
            ni = niHeight;
        }
    });

    var newsHeight = (tds - ni) / 2 + 92;
    $('div.header-left div.news').css('margin-top', newsHeight + "px");
}
```

Comment: @masha2, какая версия ie? у меня только 10 под рукой

Comment: восьмая, в других не проверяла

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@masha2](/users/6907/masha2)](/users/6907/masha2), Вам следует проверить в актуальных (7, 9). И попробовать

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

. И желательно видеть результат выполнения в консоли js.

Comment: stck, спасибо, в 9 всё работает нормально. 
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" /> только не подошел, рушится вся верстка.

Comment: @masha2, директивы хоть поставили?:) <!--[if IE 8]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" /> <!--[endif]-->